# Qt: QCamera + FaceRig (virtual camera). Is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qtmultimedia, qcamera

Is it possible to use QCamera class with physical/virtual camera which is used by another program?

I know that FaceRig is creates with possibility to be used at such programs like Skype, but when I've trying to catch it by QCamera (I use default example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html) it returns black screen with errors in the debug:

> Failed to get the video control
>
> failed to find the video proc amp

I know that the reason is that camera has currently run by another process. I do not know how to work around that.

Comment: *Is it possible to use QCamera class with physical/virtual camera which
is used by another program?*

The simple answer is "yes". It is possible.

But there is system consideration. For example Linux 4LV2 standard declares using of `open()` call and implies the driver may refuse to open the video device for more than once: https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/func-open.html

EBUSY The driver does not support multiple opens and the device is already in use. *Not sure if this qualifies as an answer. Likely not Qt level.*

Comment: Anyway it is interesting info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!!! I found the way to solve the problem for FaceRig.
I should simply to turn on broadcast (UI+ -> Broadcast)
(https://steamcommunity.com/app/274920/discussions/2/530646715641672440/)